# Cannot drop db in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I need to remove db.
I perform the following queries:

```
UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn = 'false' WHERE datname = 'myDb';

SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE datname = 'myDb' AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS 'myDb';
```

The error is `55006: cannot drop the currently open database`

Comment: You need to connect to a different database, e.g. `postgres` when you run that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name is it possible via command \c dbname? i'm getting syntax error at or near "\"

Comment: That means you are probably not using `psql`. Use your client's way of closing the database session and starting another one to a different database.